# Error creating control - GridView1. The server tag is not well formed

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm just trying to make my gridview editable, which will be filled with data from the database. When my program starts, it will connect to the database and fill the gridview with data. Now i want to edit the data in it.
I don't know what mistake I am doing due to which I am get this error in design view of visual studio `ERROR:- Error creating control - GridView1. The server tag is not well formed.`

Have a look at the tag and show me where I am making mistake.

.aspx :-

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AdminHome/AdminMainPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="questions.aspx.cs" Inherits="AdminHome_questions" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false"
AllowPaging = "true" PageSize = "10"  Font-Names = "Arial"
Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 
HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green"  OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Width="100%" HeaderText="Questions">
        

        <ItemTemplate>
            

            <asp:Table runat="server" Width="100%">
               
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Description") %></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Question") %></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow >
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Option1") %></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Option2") %></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Option3") %></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Option4") %></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("CorrectAns") %></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Explanation") %></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
                    

        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Table runat="server" Width="100%">
               
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text="<%# Eval("Description")%>"></asp:TextBox> </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text="<%# Eval("Question") %>"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow >
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text="<%# Eval("Question") %>"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text="<%# Eval("Option2") %>"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text="<%# Eval("Option3") %>"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text="<%# Eval("Option4") %>"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text="<%# Eval("CorrectAns") %>"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text="<%# Eval("Explanation") %>"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>


<asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Width="100%">
        

        <HeaderTemplate>
Sections 
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "SectionChanged" AutoPostBack = "true"
            AppendDataBoundItems = "true">
                 <asp:ListItem Text = "ALL" Value = "ALL"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text = "Top 10" Value = "10"></asp:ListItem>

             </asp:DropDownList>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<%# Eval("SectionName") %>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPageDesc" runat="Server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Columns="50"

                                Text='<%# Eval("SectionName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While binding data to textbox you write **text="<%# Eval("Description")%>"** instead write text=**'<%# Eval("Description")%>'**

Instead of **""** write **''**.

Same for all TextBox.

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AdminHome/AdminMainPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="questions.aspx.cs" Inherits="AdminHome_questions" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false"
AllowPaging = "true" PageSize = "10"  Font-Names = "Arial"
Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 
HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green"  OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Width="100%" HeaderText="Questions">
        

        <ItemTemplate>
            

            <asp:Table runat="server" Width="100%">
               
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Description") %></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Question") %></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow >
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Option1") %></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Option2") %></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Option3") %></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Option4") %></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("CorrectAns") %></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <%# Eval("Explanation") %></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
                    

        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Table runat="server" Width="100%">
               
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Description")%>'></asp:TextBox> </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow >
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Option2") %>'></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Option3") %>'></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Option4") %>"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text='<%# Eval("CorrectAns") %>'></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow width="100%">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Explanation") %>'></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>


<asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Width="100%">
        

        <HeaderTemplate>
Sections 
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "SectionChanged" AutoPostBack = "true"
            AppendDataBoundItems = "true">
                 <asp:ListItem Text = "ALL" Value = "ALL"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text = "Top 10" Value = "10"></asp:ListItem>

             </asp:DropDownList>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<%# Eval("SectionName") %>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPageDesc" runat="Server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Columns="50"

                                Text='<%# Eval("SectionName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: How stupid I am ! Such a silly mistake I did..Thank you so much